# Unlocking iPad 2 (iOS 7) with the Apple ID credentials

Tags: apple-id, security

Someone set a passcode to my iPad, and he can't remember what it is. Now I can't open it, I'm always asked for 4-digit passcode. But, I **do** know my Apple ID credentials, and my iPad is connected to my Apple Account.

I know that in Android based devices there is an option to skip the passcode screen using the Google Account of the device, but I can't find similar way in my iPad.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but there is no way to bypass a forgotten password. You must restore it in iTunes. If your device is backed up in iCloud or iTunes, you can restore your data.

[iOS: Forgot passcode or device disabled](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1212)