# Unlock a locked 32GB iPad

Tags: itunes, ipad, icloud

I have an iPad (32GB) and have been locked out because I couldn't remember the passcode.
What can I do?

I have never associated it with an iTunes account but want to get the pictures off it (which do not appear in iCloud)

Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unlocking iPad 2 (iOS 7) with the Apple ID credentials](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/148173/unlocking-ipad-2-ios-7-with-the-apple-id-credentials)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming by *'iTunes account'* you are referring to an *'iCloud account'*.

Photos won't appear in iCloud for that reason (no account to sync with).
No iCloud account associated with the iPad means no backup location to restore from or other form of cloud storage.

You may use iTunes to reset your iPad to factory default or restore it from a backup (should you have one) while the iPad is in recovery mode.
There are already tutorials specifically outlining every step of this process, hence I won't post them here.

This is just one of the 100+ available on YouTube: [Video Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XJanCW0goks)

At this moment I am unsure if this answers your question or not, as I can't quite make out the actual question(s). Let me know how you get on.